# getting Problem when return selected columns in the form of list in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to return specific columns in list in entity framework . but i am getting the error [image]

Comment: Could you post an example of the data, in addition to an example of the current and desired outcome please?

Comment: Is that expected output or current, incorrect, output? And can you post an example of the input?

Comment: Please provide some sample data of both tables. `sale` and `sale detail`

Comment: this is not the expected output . this is the incorrect one

Comment: then please show the required / expected result

Comment: It's very hard to help you since you refuse to improve the quality of your question as requested but from your latest image (!) it looks like you should use `COUNT()` rather than `SUM()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a windowed `count` on your `SaleID` values to get the number of detail rows that are returned for each, which would change your script to the following:

```
SELECT NS.saleid, 
   NS.saledate, 
   P.NAME, 
   (NS.discount / Att.quantity) / count(NS.saleid) over (partition by NS.saleid) as  AS OrderLevelDiscount,
   NSD.discount  AS ItemLevelDiscount 
FROM   salesdetail NSD 
   INNER JOIN sales NS 
           ON NSD.saleid = NS.saleid 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT saleid, 
                      CASE 
                        WHEN Sum(quantity) IS NULL THEN 0 
                        ELSE Sum(quantity) 
                      END AS Quantity 
               FROM   salesdetail 
               GROUP  BY saleid) Att 
           ON NS .saleid = Att.saleid 
   LEFT JOIN productsmanager P 
          ON NSD.productcode = P.code
```

Comment: @AnisulHassan  Subquery?  The windowed function in my answer is almost certainly more efficient...